# UnsatisfiedDependencyException:Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'

Tags: spring-boot, controller, dependencies, repository, autowired

I am facing the below error:

-Cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.EmployeeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Below is my code(I have not made any service class on purpose,by adding service class same error occurred)

EmployeeController.java

```java
    @RestController
    public class EmployeeController {
    
        @Autowired
        EmployeeRepository repository;
        
        @PostMapping("/employee/add")
        public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp)
        {
            return repository.save(emp);
        }
        
        @GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
        public Optional<Employee> getEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id)
        {
            return repository.findById(id);
        }
        
        @PutMapping("/employee/{id}")
        public Employee updateEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id,@RequestBody Employee emp)
        {
            Optional<Employee> employee=repository.findById(id);
            if(employee.isPresent())
            {
                return repository.save(emp);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        @DeleteMapping("/employee/{id}")
        public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Integer id)
        {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            return "Document Deleted";
        }
            
        }
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```java
    @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Employee, Integer>{
        
    
    }
```

I am unable to understand why `employeeController` is unable to get dependency of `employeeRepository` when `@Autowired` has been used. Please let me know what is wrong here

Comment: are you using the correct imports for the annotations?

Comment: yes, imports being -> import com.example.demo.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; these for EmployeeController                                                                                                    
  and the following for EmployeeRepository-> package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a configuration class that extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration and override its methods where you will need to specify Couchbase’s IP address, bucket name, username, and password. I hope it should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import package org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

Because if you go to the CouchBaseRepository, it has been extended not from stereotype:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/repository/CouchbaseRepository.html

Comment: If I am doing so(changing my import from org.springframework.stereotype.Repository; to import package org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;),  my @Repository annotation is not working and showing error

Comment: This means you need to check for your maven imports